# Can I symlink multiple directories into one?

Tags: unix, symlink

I have a feeling that I already know the answer to this one, but I thought I'd check.

I have a number of different folders:

```
images_a/
images_b/
images_c/
```

Can I create some sort of symlink such that this new directory has the contents of all those directories? That is this new "`images_all`" would contain all the files in `images_a`, `images_b` and `images_c`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. You would have to symbolically link all the individual files.

What you *could* do is to create a job to run periodically which basically removed all of the existing symbolic links in `images_all`, then re-create the links for all files from the three other directories, but it's a bit of a kludge, something like this:

```bash
rm -f images_all/*
for i in images_[abc]/* ; do; ln -s $i images_all/$(basename $i) ; done
```

Note that, while this job is running, it may appear to other processes that the files have temporarily disappeared.

You will also need to watch out for the case where a single file name exists in two or more of the directories.

---

Having come back to this question after a while, it also occurs to me that you can minimise the time during which the files are not available.

If you link them to a *different* directory then do relatively fast `mv` operations that would minimise the time. Something like:

```bash
mkdir images_new
for i in images_[abc]/* ; do
    ln -s $i images_new/$(basename $i)
done

# These next two commands are the minimal-time switchover.
mv images_all images_old
mv images_new images_all

rm -rf images_old
```

I haven't tested that so anyone implementing it will have to confirm the suitability or otherwise.

Comment: You can use `lndir` to do the symlinking.

Comment: just add an if statement that checks if the file already exists in the destination. no need to delete... sorry for commenting on a 11 year old post

Answer (score 11):

You could try a unioning file system like unionfs!

http://www.filesystems.org/project-unionfs.html

http://aufs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: And the phrase "is still in development stage" strikes fear into the hearts of even the bravest soul :-).

Comment: `aufs` has been used in Ubuntu for a while, so it's probably stable enough.

Comment: And has by now largely been superseded by Overlayfs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS

Answer (score 3):

to add on to paxdiablo 's great answer,  i think you could use cp -s
(-s or --symbolic-link)
which makes symbolic links instead of literal copying

to maybe speed up or simplify the the bulk adding of symlinks to the "merge" folder A , of the files from folder B and C.

(i have not tested this though)

I cant recall of the top of my head, but im sure there is some option for CP to NOT overwrite existing,  thus only symlinks of new files will be "cp -s" ed