# Git: multiple subtrees/submodules in one folder?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

On a local machine, I have common scripts which are imported by several projects, e.g.:

```
/common/
  .git/
  scripts/
    common1.py
/projectA/
  .git/
  scripts/
    A1.py (imports from common1.py)
/projectB/
  .git/
  scripts/
    B1.py (imports from common1.py)
```

Common scripts and projects are tracked in separate git repos. This works fine for my personal work because I can clone all repos needed. When making a project publically available via git, I can include common files via subtrees or submodules (references to common files are updated in B1.py obviously):

```
/projectB/
  .git/
  scripts/
    common/ (subtree from common)
      common1.py
    B1.py
```

Now I'd like to assemble a superproject (the target):

```
/projectC/
  .git/
  scripts/
    common1.py
    A1.py
    B1.py
```

With subtrees and submodules I've been able to achieve:

```
/projectC/
  .git/
  scripts/
    common/
      common1.py
    projectA_scripts/ (via subtree)
      A1.py
      common/ (via subtree w/in projectA)
        common1.py
    projectB_scripts/ (via subtree)
      B1.py
      common/ (via subtree w/in projectB)
        common1.py 
    C1.py
```

However this is quite redundant and propagating changes through the sub-x chain will be tedious. How can I achieve the target directory structure above while retaining the ability to pull updates to project and common files? For what it's worth I don't expect to need to push subtree/submodule changes upstream.

Bonus for cross-platform (Windows-UNIX) solutions that don't require independent configuration on both OS's. Git-based solutions preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have to push those subtree/submodule content back, you *could* consider [symlink those folders into `common/`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/423320/6309):

- either by symlinking each files of those subtrees/submodules.
- or using [aufs-tools](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/), which should allow "[unite several directories into a single virtual filesystem](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/linux-aufs/)".

Comment: Interesting approach - certainly could work. I didn't mention in the OP, but I'm hoping for a cross-platform Windows-UNIX solution that wouldn't require independent configuration in both OS's (as symlinks would). Git-based solutions are preferred.

Comment: @metasequoia Well, Windows has symlink too ;) ([mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), which requires administrative privileges)