# .gitignore files when 2 git repo in same directory

Tags: git, shell, gitignore

**Context**

I have 2 git repositories (gitone and gittwo) in one directory.

For setting them up, I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17313342/10079397).

So now, I have two aliases:

```
alias gitone='git --git-dir=.gitone'
alias gittwo='git --git-dir=.gittwo'
```

**Problem**

I want to ignore distinct files in each repo.

**Solution?**

I created a .gitignore:

```
# Ignore everything ...
*

# ... except ...
!/.gitignore
!/gittwo-ignore.txt
!*.sql

# ... from all directories and subdirectories
!*/
```

I want `.gitignore` to work for gitone, but not for gittwo. For this, I created `gittwo-ignore.txt`:

```
# Ignore everything (including gitignore)...
*

# ... except ...
!*.ipynb
!/gittwo-ignore.txt

# ... from all directories and subdirectories
!*/
```

and I added it to the core.excludesfile:

```
gittwo config --global core.excludesfile ~/gittwo-ignore.txt
gittwo rm -r --cached .
gittwo add .
gittwo commit -m 'Hopefully this now works'
gittwo push origin master
```

I was hoping that with `gittwo-ignore.txt`, gittwo would ignore `.gitignore` and only take into account the rules from `gittwo-ignore.txt`.

Unfortunately, my repo gittwo still only contains .sql files (so only takes into account the ignore rules from .gitignore).

How can I fix this?

Comment: What about removing .gitignore altogether and setting a custom exclude file for gitone as well?

Comment: @Papooch short story, gitone is meant to be cloned by my coworkers. They need to see the .gitignore file in the git repo.

Comment: Maybe this could help, then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994612/is-there-a-way-to-tell-git-status-to-ignore-the-effects-of-gitignore-files
Another think I thought of is, instead of keeping both git repos in a single folder, you could keep them separate and symlink content from both to a separate directory, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423320/can-i-symlink-multiple-directories-into-one or https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/symlink-two-dirs-into-one-327587/